# Is there a way to pass variables except sessions and get variables?

Tags: php, url, parameter-passing

My problem is not so easy to describe ... for me :-) so please be lenient towards me.

I have several ways to view a list. which means, there are some possibilities how to come to and create the view which displays my list. this wokrs well with parallel opend browser tabs and is desired though.

if I click on an item of my list I come to a detail-view of that item.

at this view I want to know from which type of list the link was "called". the first problem is, that the referrer will allways be the same and the second: I should not append a get variable to the url. (and it should not be a submitted form too)

if I store it to the session, I will overwrite my session param when working in a parallel tab as well.

what is the best way to still achive my goal, of knowing which mode the previous list was in.

Comment: "I should not append a get variable to the url. (and it should not be a submitted form too)" Why not?

Comment: to have userfriendly urls (no get) and to be able to use the backbutton in all browsers (no form).

Comment: You should look into `mod_rewrite` -- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html.

Comment: and if i don't have access to the server configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use *something* to differentiate one page from another, otherwise your server won't know what you're asking for.

You can POST your request: this will hide the URL parameters, but will hinder your back button functionality.

You can GET your request: this will make your URLs more "ugly" but you should be able to work around that by passing short, concise identifiers like www.example.com/listDetail?id=12

If you can set up mod_rewrite, then you can GET requests to a url like www.example.com/listDetails/12, and apache will rewrite the request *behind the scenes* to look more like www.example.com/listDetails?id=12 **but the user will never see it** -- they will just see the original, clean/friendly version.

You said you don't have access to the server configuration -- I assume this is because you are on a shared server? *Most* shared servers already have mod_rewrite installed. And while the apache vhost is typically the most appropriate place to put rewrite rules, they can *also* be put in a .htaccess file within any directory you want to control. (Sometimes the server configuration disables this, but usually on a shared host, it is enabled) Look into creating [.htaccess](http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/htaccess/) files and how to use [mod_rewrite](http://www.easymodrewrite.com/)